# Laravel redirecting project to "projectURL/public/public"

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

first of all this are my laravel and PHP versions:
Laravel Framework 7.17.2
PHP 7.3.19 (cli)

I am having a wierd problem with my laravel project:

**in my vhost file I have:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.name.test
    DocumentRoot "C:\web\name\name\backend\public"
</VirtualHost>
```

**in the hosts file:**

127.0.0.1           [www.name.test](http://www.name.test)

when trying to acces the project by typing:
http://www.name.test
it redirects me to the url
http://www.name.test/public/public

I have .htaccess in my root folder and in the public folder with the following :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I dont know why this started to happen, previously it was working fine but sth I gues was changed accidentally on the project since it happens in everycomputer, so it does not look like a php configuration problem.

hope someone can give some tip about the issue.

Comment: What is your PHP and Laravel version?

Comment: version 7 laravel,Laravel Framework 7.17.2, php PHP 7.3.19 (cli)

Comment: edited post with the versions

Comment: @Joaquin86 is it working fine after adding public "http://www.name.test/public/public" ?

Comment: @GauravGupta, it is not, in that url I do not have any controller

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to fix this issue:

**Step 1:**

Just rename your `server.php` to `index.php` file present in your project root directory.

**Step 2:**

Copy `index.php` present inside public folder of your project root directory and paste it inside the root directory. Make sure there is no other `index.php` present before.

Then replace these 2 lines:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

with

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Hope either of the 2 ways helps!!

Comment: thank you very much for this information, iit gave me some ideas about where to check for the errors, definetly it has been a mess with the redirections